# Corollary of Schur's Lemma - why abelian

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Corollary (of Schur's Lemma): Every irreducible complex representation of a finite abelian group G is one-dimensional.

My question is now, why has the group to be abelian? As far as I know, we want the representation $\rho(g)$ to be a $Hom_G(V,V)$, where $V$ is the representation space. Isn't this always the case (i.e. even if the $\rho(g)$ is not abelian) as it is by definition a function $G \rightarrow GL(V)$?

Comment: Do you know how to use Schur's lemma to prove this? The hypothesis that $G$ is abelian is crucial to the proof.

Comment: Well, I do understand the part of the proof where I have to use the fact, that if there is a $Hom_G (V,V)$ then the representation is = \lambda * id. From this then follows that all subspaces have to be irreducible and with the irreducibility of $\rho$ itself, that it is one-dimensional.

Comment: Do you understand where in the proof you need the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: I need it just in the beginning in order to justify that there is indeed a $Hom_G(V,V)$. But here lies my problem. I don't really understand why this is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is, that for a abelian group every element is a intertwining operator. This means let $h \in G$, then $\rho(h)\rho(g)\rho(h^{-1})=\rho(g)$ for all $g$ and therefore by Schur's lemma $\rho(h)=\lambda id$. Since your representation was assumed to be irreducible it follows that it is one dimensional. Note that we used the commutativity of the group here in an essential way. This is no longer true for non abelian groups.

Comment: So you are using the fact that a homomorphism $(\rho_1,V_1) \rightarrow (\rho_2,V_2)$ is a linear function $\phi:V_1 \rightarrow V_2$ such that $\phi \rho_1(g)=\rho_2(g) \phi$ and $\rho$ is such a $\phi:V \rightarrow V$ itself?

Comment: @Quasar Precisely. It depents a little bit on your formulation of Schur's lemma, but I think this is the most commonly used version in representation theory. In your notation every $h$ gives a $\phi$ namely $\phi=\rho(h)$. Now use the lemma.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that's where my problem was.

Answer (score 1):

Any finite group is isomorphic to a direct product of its irreducible representations, acting on a direct sum of vector spaces. If all irreducible representations are one-dimensional then this faithful representation consists of diagonal matrices which commute. Whence the group is abelian.

Comment: The problem here is: How do I know that all irreducible representations are one-dimensional?

Comment: So if the group is Abelien then why an irreducible representation is one-dimensional? As I recall a $d\geq 2$ dimensional representation is either reducible or must have non-commuting elements. But this may be non-trivial to show ...?

Comment: In fact this amounts to proving Schur's lemma. One version of the Lemma: Let $S$ be a collection of maps on a Hilbert space $E$. (Here $S$ is our collection of matrices in our representation).  If $A$ is normal (i.e. $A^*A=AA^*$) and $A$ and $A^*$ commute with all $T\in S$ then either $S$ leaves a proper subspace invariant (so the representation was not irreducible) or $A=cI$. So if irreducible and all elements in $S$ commute they are all proportional to $I$. And again since irreducible we must be in dimension 1.

Comment: Together with Maik Pickl's answer this solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Don't know if it is of interest to you, but in finite dimension there is a simple proof of Schur's lemma:

 Suppose $A$ is not proportional to $I$. Then it has two distinct eigenvalues (it is here one needs normality). Let's call $\lambda_1$ one of them and $E_1$ the eigenspace associated. Then the polynomial $P_1(A)= \prod_{\lambda<>\lambda_1} (A-\lambda I)$ (the other evals)  maps $E$ onto $E_1$,  $P_1(A) E_1=E_1$ and commutes with all $T\in S$. By hypothesis: $T E_1=T P_1(A) E_1= P_1(A) T E_1 \subset E_1$ so every $T\in S$ leaves $E_1$ invariant. qed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, for maybe longer than a year, but because of a stupid mistake in understanding Schur's. Here it is, in case ( hoping ;) ) that someone else might do the same mistake:

Schur's lemma says something about >any< linear $\psi$ so that

(*) $ \;\;\;\; \psi \rho (g) = \rho (g) \psi$ $\;$  $\forall g$

for some irreducible representation $\rho$. (Correct me if there are more assumptions.) $\psi$ is not assumed to be irreducible. If you would assume it is irreducible, it would follow from Schur's lemma that it's one dimensional, already at this stage. But you don't know that.

(In the corollary, you have $\psi = \rho $, so $\psi$ is irreducible now. But you still need (*), which you get from G's abelianness, as the others have pointed out.)